# Cone and lock nut adjustment on the drive side is impossible on my back wheel

Tags: hub, cones

The right side cone is covered with a cup style spacer and the cone wrench cannot be used to fully tighten the lock nut. I think this metal cup serves as some kind of seal. How can I retighten cone and nut ?

Comment: You might want to add some more details - is this rear or front hub? Does the wheel have disc or rim brake? Maybe add a photo?

Answer (score 4):

On quite a few hubs (particularly rear hubs), cone and locknut are only adjustable on one side. The other side is tightened during assembly, before inserting the axle into the hub. If your left side is adjustable, the solution is to undo the left side, take the axle completely out, tighten things on the right, then reassemble and use left side for final adjustment.

Comment: Sometimes you can get enough access on the drive side with the cassette (or more precisely its lockring) removed, but generally I've found final adjustment to be far better on the left, when it's usually possible even in the frame

Comment: Addendum: if the locknuts have completely undone themselves on both sides, make sure to leave about equal axle length outside the tightened locknuts on both sides (so you have enough axle to hold the wheel in place). It will require careful measurement (e.g., take full axle width, subtract nominal hub width, i.e., the actual width between the dropouts, divide by two - that's what you expect to leave outside the tightened locknut) and/or several trial-and-error adjustments.